# QtSingleApplication for PySide or PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

Is there a Python version of the C++ class [`QtSingleApplication`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsingleapplication/qtsingleapplication.html) from [Qt Solutions](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-Add-Ons/Qt-Solutions-Archive/)?

[`QtSingleApplication`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsingleapplication/qtsingleapplication.html) is used to make sure that there can never be more than one instance of an application running at the same time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is my own implementation.
It has been tested with Python 2.7 and PySide 1.1.

It has essentially the same interface as the [C++ version of `QtSingleApplication`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsingleapplication/qtsingleapplication.html). The main difference is that you must supply an application unique id to the constructor. (The C++ version by default uses the path to the executable as a unique id; that would not work here because the executable will most likely be `python.exe`.)

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtNetwork import *

class QtSingleApplication(QApplication):

    messageReceived = Signal(unicode)

    def __init__(self, id, *argv):

        super(QtSingleApplication, self).__init__(*argv)
        self._id = id
        self._activationWindow = None
        self._activateOnMessage = False

        # Is there another instance running?
        self._outSocket = QLocalSocket()
        self._outSocket.connectToServer(self._id)
        self._isRunning = self._outSocket.waitForConnected()

        if self._isRunning:
            # Yes, there is.
            self._outStream = QTextStream(self._outSocket)
            self._outStream.setCodec('UTF-8')
        else:
            # No, there isn't.
            self._outSocket = None
            self._outStream = None
            self._inSocket = None
            self._inStream = None
            self._server = QLocalServer()
            self._server.listen(self._id)
            self._server.newConnection.connect(self._onNewConnection)

    def isRunning(self):
        return self._isRunning

    def id(self):
        return self._id

    def activationWindow(self):
        return self._activationWindow

    def setActivationWindow(self, activationWindow, activateOnMessage = True):
        self._activationWindow = activationWindow
        self._activateOnMessage = activateOnMessage

    def activateWindow(self):
        if not self._activationWindow:
            return
        self._activationWindow.setWindowState(
            self._activationWindow.windowState() & ~Qt.WindowMinimized)
        self._activationWindow.raise_()
        self._activationWindow.activateWindow()

    def sendMessage(self, msg):
        if not self._outStream:
            return False
        self._outStream << msg << '\n'
        self._outStream.flush()
        return self._outSocket.waitForBytesWritten()

    def _onNewConnection(self):
        if self._inSocket:
            self._inSocket.readyRead.disconnect(self._onReadyRead)
        self._inSocket = self._server.nextPendingConnection()
        if not self._inSocket:
            return
        self._inStream = QTextStream(self._inSocket)
        self._inStream.setCodec('UTF-8')
        self._inSocket.readyRead.connect(self._onReadyRead)
        if self._activateOnMessage:
            self.activateWindow()

    def _onReadyRead(self):
        while True:
            msg = self._inStream.readLine()
            if not msg: break
            self.messageReceived.emit(msg)
```

Here is a simple test program:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from QtSingleApplication import QtSingleApplication

appGuid = 'F3FF80BA-BA05-4277-8063-82A6DB9245A2'
app = QtSingleApplication(appGuid, sys.argv)
if app.isRunning(): sys.exit(0)

w = QWidget()
w.show()
app.setActivationWindow(w)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why don't you use the script filename `/path/to/script.py` instead of a UUID?

Comment: @Hugo: Does that work if you are running a frozen egg or a py2exe or PyInstaller executable?

Comment: I've no idea, I've never used python with windows or pyinstaller.

Comment: Hi @user763305, is it OK to use this under a BSD license or something similar?

Comment: @Thomas K: Feel free to use the code under the 2-clause BSD license, http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause

Comment: How would one .show() original app instead of just exit the new instance?

Comment: @DoTheEvo Take a look at the `QtSingleApplication` [docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtsingleapplication/qtsingleapplication.html), especially the `sendMessage` slot and the `messageReceived` signal.

Comment: @user763305 I tried, I am failing, heres my idea how to use it on your given example http://pastebin.com/8KQ7WgZj

I tried to follow it inside the class, but seems it never gets to emit, never get in to _onNewConnection in my usage and various variation I had.

isRunning works all right, if I use sendMessage I get no errors and it behaves strangely but no errors and I have to keep changing the id.

also python3 here if that might be the problem, I changed unicode in signal to str

Comment: @DoTheEvo I found one issue in your code; `new_instance_messaging` is not a member function, so you should omit the `self` argument. (Also, in the `if app.isRunning():` block, you should terminate the new instance after you send the message.)

Comment: Upvoted. I'd +100 this if I could, as it's tremendously helpful. Also fyi, I've discovered a problem: UUID = X was working last night, but no longer working this morn on the same MacOS 10.9.5 machine (same login). UUID = X+1 now works on said system. Could possibly be due to ongoing development for my application (test runs, process hangs, etc), but I've killed all related python processes I could find. I've not yet attempted further debugging. I'll post here if I discover any further, significant info.

Comment: @user763305 per my above, Apr 6 post, I've had to continually update the UUID as I further update/develop my application. Is this to be expected?

Comment: @Johnny Utahh: That is not expected. The only explanation I can think of is that an old instance is still running in the background.

Comment: Thanks. Initial modification + testing suggests that symptoms might be due to previously-missing QLocalServer cleanup/removal.  It's early and immature, but I have yet to experience symptoms (with semi-repeatable test case) based upon the following code, which represents modifications I made to @user763305's above code: http://gist.github.com/johnnyutahh/e7754a70ccf7972feae5 . It seems best if the calling application calls QtSingleApplication.close() during application clean exit/shutdown and/or in high-level try/exception catches.

Comment: @user763305 (continuing from above...) The `QLocalServer.removeServer(self._id)` attempts to cleanup after any previously-crashed/unclosed servers. This could (maybe?) include previous servers failing to call `QtSingleApplication.close()`. In any case, the `.removeServer()` call seems to have fixed my previously "stuck" QLocalServer's.

Comment: @user763305 I'm running python 2.7.8 and pyqt 4.11.3 on Mac OS 10.9.5. I'd expect the following (albeit untested) changes are sufficient to run in PySide: `s/pyqtSignal/Signal/` and `s/PyQt4/PySide/`.

Comment: Johan’s code was put to good use: https://github.com/Bitmessage/PyBitmessage/blame/v0.6/src/bitmessageqt/__init__.py#L4085 thanks!

Comment: With Qt6, replace calls to `setCodec('UTF-8')` with `setEncoding(QStringConverter.Utf8)`, e.g. `self._inStream.setEncoding(QStringConverter.Utf8)`

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look to this [blog entry](http://www.dallagnese.fr/en/computers-it/recette-python-qt4-qsingleapplication-pyside/). It is for Pyside but I guess that it will work too with PyQt4.

Comment: That Python class has an interface that is quite different from the interface of the C++ class. In particular, you must give the constructor a reference to the main window, and the constructor will then call show() on the main window asynchronously.

Comment: Well I'm not saying this is the perfect, definitive solution. It is a user implemented solution and I guess that preserving the C++ interface was not one author's priority. Instead it seems he preferred to add some features in the way that arguments can be passed from later invocations to the first one.

Comment: Passing arguments from later invocations to the first one is possible with the original C++ interface through the `sendMessage` method and the `messageReceived` signal.

Comment: Then I suppose I would use your implementation as it seems to be better designed. As I said, I guess the author had his own priorities and obviously they weren't the same as yours :)